# How do i change the code so that the player stops at the edges rather than wrapping around?

Tags: python, pygame, game-development

```
WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 500

background = Actor("background")
player = Actor("player")
player.x = 200
player.y = 200

def draw():
screen.clear()
background.draw()
player.draw()

def update():
if keyboard.right:
    player.x = player.x + 4
if keyboard.left:
    player.x = player.x - 4
if keyboard.down:
    player.y = player.y + 4
if keyboard.up:
    player.y = player.y - 4

if player.x > WIDTH:
    player.x = 0
if player.x < 0:
    player.x = WIDTH
if player.y < 0:
    player.y = HEIGHT
if player.y > HEIGHT:
    player.y = 0
```

I want to make the player stop at the edges instead of wrapping around and teleporting to the other side. Help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have it the wrong way around:

```
if player.x > WIDTH:
    player.x = WIDTH
if player.x < 0:
    player.x = 0
if player.y < 0:
    player.y = 0
if player.y > HEIGHT:
    player.y = HEIGHT
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: This is not quite right, though it is not entirely the fault of the responder..To do it properly requires the width and height of the player, which is not in the code shown.. This works fine for the top and the left side, but will allow the player to go all the way off the bottom and right sides.  If the `x` is the left edge and the `y` is the top edge, then to stop it going off the x+width and y+height is needed for the check and they should be subtracted when trying to limit the player on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

There's already an answer but I think that this code would be more efficient.

```
def update():
 if keyboard.right and player.x<=WIDTH-4:
  player.x = player.x + 4
 if keyboard.left and player.x>=4:
  player.x = player.x - 4
 if keyboard.down and player.y<=HEIGHT-4:
  player.y = player.y + 4
 if keyboard.up and player.y>=4:
  player.y = player.y - 4
```